# SharePoint Web Part - RAISERROR in stored procedure causing causing 403

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, sharepoint-2010

I have a web part that calls a SQL Server stored procedure and when an error is raised, the SharePoint page is supposed to show the error message via a label.

However, when an error is raised in the stored procedure the SharePoint page shows a 403 error. When no error is raised, the page behaves as expected.

This problem only occurs for standard users (site visitors), and if I execute this code as a SharePoint administrator, it all works fine, so I'm guessing it's a permissions problem of some description.

Can anyone help please? Thanks.

The SQL code looks like this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProcedure
(
    @SomeValue INT
)

AS

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn = @SomeValue)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Already completed.', 16, 1);
    RETURN;
END;

-- otherwise do something
```

with C# code such as:

```
    private void UpdateSomething()
    {
        string errorMessage;

        errorMessage = DataAccess.UpdateSomeValue(strSomeValue);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
        {
            lblInformationMessage.Text = "Update completed successfully.";
            lblInformationMessage.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Text = string.Concat("There was an error: ", errorMessage);
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

That calls the following:

```
    public static string UpdateSomeValue(string strSomeValue)
    {

        string errorMessage = "";
        SqlConnection cnn;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        try
        {
            //connection
            cnn = new SqlConnection(strCnn);
            cnn.Open();

            //command
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.SomeProcedure";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SomeValue", SqlDbType.Int, 18));
            cmd.Parameters["@SomeValue"].Value = strSomeValue;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cnn.Close();

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
            Utility.Writelog(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString());
            Utility.Writelog(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

        return errorMessage;
    }
```

Comment: Is the log being written to when the exception occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it works admin why not run it elevated

spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges(delegate()
{

errorMessage = DataAccess.UpdateSomeValue(strSomeValue);

});

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. Ideally I'd like to know why it doesn't work as it works fine on the development SharePoint server, but this could be a useful fix for the time being.

Comment: Thanks, yes this has worked, but I would like to see if there are other solutions? Changing something in the SharePoint configuration maybe?

Comment: It will have something todo with who has execute permission in your SQL db. What context is the storep running in.

Comment: The connection to the SQL Server is via a SQL login (it's always the same user) and the it's always to the same database and server. Elevating the privileges in SharePoint fixed the problem, which leads me to believe that it's a problem at the SharePoint end. Thanks.